# Create dynamic SQL statement for one year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to compare the number of newly made subscriptions with the number of ending subscriptions per month in 2018 and combine that into one table.

With x-axis being the months of 2018 (so January, February, and so on) and y-axis as first row my first sql query = the number of ran out subscriptions in that month. The second row would be my second sql query = the number of newly made subscriptions in that month. My "queries" down there are as an example for March 2018.

```
SELECT    
    COUNT (UserId)
FROM
    UserInAppPurchase 
WHERE 
    ValidTo > '2018-03-01' AND ValidTo < '2018-03-31' 
GROUP BY
    UserId

SELECT COUNT(UserId)
FROM UserInAppPurchase 
WHERE PurchaseDate > '2018-03-01' 
  AND PurchaseDate < '2018-03-31' 
GROUP BY UserId
```

Thanks very much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it right, the above query will return multiple rows for a single month which will depend to the total number of unique users placing order. Then for each month and each user being two verticals, the said graph will be a 3D-graph which I don't think the case here is.
So Instead, I could think of 2 cases,

1. You want total number of subscriptions expired per month of each month

   ```
   SELECT MONTH(ValidTo) ExpireMonth, COUNT(UserId) ExpireCount
   FROM UserInAppPurchase 
   WHERE YEAR(ValidTo) = 2018
   GROUP BY MONTH(ValidTo);
   ```
2. You want to know the number of users whose at least one subscription have expired

   ```
   WITH UniqueUsers AS
   (
       SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(ValidTo) ExpireMonth, UserId
       FROM UserInAppPurchase 
       WHERE YEAR(ValidTo) = 2018
   )
   SELECT ExpireMonth, COUNT(UserId) UserCount
   FROM UniqueUsers
   GROUP BY ExpireMonth;
   ```

The similar query will be for purchased subscriptions as well.

Please let me know if what you require is different.

Comment: thanks a lot. Second case is what I was looking for. Is it anyhow possible to put the output of 2. into one result table together with the number of purchases made (also the number of users whose at least have purchased one new subscription)

Comment: Try this:
WITH PurchaseUsers AS
(SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(PurchaseDate) SubMon, UserId
FROM UserInAppPurchase 
WHERE YEAR(PurchaseDate) = 2018
),
PurchaseUserCount AS
(
SELECT SubMon, COUNT(UserId) UserCount
FROM PurchaseUsers
GROUP BY SubMon
),
UniqueUsers AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(ValidTo) SubMon, UserId
FROM UserInAppPurchase 
WHERE YEAR(ValidTo) = 2018
),
UniqueUserCount AS
(
SELECT SubMon, COUNT(UserId) UserCount
FROM UniqueUsers
GROUP BY SubMon
)
SELECT A.SubMon, A.UserCount, B.UserCount
FROM PurchaseUserCount A
JOIN UniqueUserCount B
ON A.SubMon = B.SubMon;

Comment: thanks a lot but it is just the same result than your initial solution

Answer (score 1):

if you want the count of user id you should not group by for user id

```
SELECT    COUNT (UserId), 'valid_to'
FROM      UserInAppPurchase WHERE ValidTo>'2018-03-01' and  ValidTo<'2018-03-31' 
union  all  
SELECT    COUNT (UserId), 'PurchaseDate'
FROM      UserInAppPurchase WHERE PurchaseDate>'2018-03-01' and PurchaseDate<'2018-03-31'
```